# datatables.net data in JSON form not displaying error tn/4

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, vb.net, datatables

Hey all I have the following JSON coming from a web service using AJAX:

```
{
 "data": [
  [
   "11/11/2014 3:02:37 PM",
   "4/13/2015 8:26:37 AM",
   "032650147",
   "NULL",
   "Web Site Problems",
   "NULL",
   "New",
   "6230.758742407"
  ],
  [
   ...etc etc....
  ]
 ]
}
```

And I am dynamically creating the HTML table like so:

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>Contact Date Time</th>
        <th>Last Update Date Time</th>
        <th>Member ID</th>
        <th>Operator NTID</th>
        <th>Question</th>
        <th>Redirect Email Address</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Receipt Date</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
</table>
```

And the Javasscript that I am using to display the returned data in the table is:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   crossDomain: true,
   url: "complete.aspx/getMemberEmailsDBData",
   beforeSend: function (xhrObj) {
       xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
   },
   data: {},
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.d);
        $('#example').DataTable({
           data: data.d,
           columns: [
              { title: "ContactDateTime" },
              { title: "LastUpdateDateTime" },
              { title: "MemberID" },
              { title: "OperatorNTID" },
              { title: "QuestionArea" },
              { title: "RedirectEmailAddress" },
              { title: "Status" },
              { title: "ReceiptDate" }
           ] 
        });
   },
   error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
   }
});
```

After loading the page up, it keeps giving me the alert popup telling me that:

> DataTables warning: Table id=example - requested unknown parameter '1'
>   for row 0, column 1. For more information about this error, please see
>   http://datatables.net/tn/4.

Anyone seeing something that I am missing in order to fix this?

Comment: What does `console.log(data.d); `output?

Comment: The JSON that I posted in my OP above.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
data: data.d.data,
```

when you are using a [javascript array source](https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html), dataTables does **not** expect the source wrapped into a `data : [ ... ]`, but simply an array of arrays.

your code in a little demo ->  **http://jsfiddle.net/jusbngww/**

Comment: if you try `console.log(data.d.data)` it outputs an `array[x]`?  You should by certain have well formed JSON at this point.

Comment: I get an **undefined** when using **console.log(data.d.data)**

Comment: @StealthRT, So, actually you are not even sure you have valid JSON or a `d` in your response? Have you tried something like `data = JSON.parse(data)`?